# Google Maps API v3 polylines tabbed InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis

I am having some difficulties with getting tabbed info windows to appear for paths. I have followed [this tutorial](http://googlemapapitutorial.com/customizedinfowindow1.jsp).

I have a KML layer with polylines (they curve - represent topographic features) 
and do not know how to get the info window to appear when you click on a path. I've seen some tutorials on calculating midpoints (but of straight lines)..

2 ways (of many) I've tried to get path points:

```
var streamPoly = google.maps.Polyline.prototype.getPosition = function() {
return this.getPath().getAt(0);}

var streamPoly = poly.getPath();
```

What's in my header:

```
var map;
var streamPoly;

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.687984,-79.394159);

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'paths.kml'
    });
    ctaLayer.setMap(map);
    ctaLayer.set('preserveViewport', true); 


    var  infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
        maxWidth: 300
    });

    var div = document.createElement('DIV');
    div.innerHTML = 'Hello';

    infoBubble.addTab('Tab 1', div);
    infoBubble.addTab('Tab 2', "<B>This is tab 2</B>");

    google.maps.event.addListener(streamPoly, 'click', function() {
        if (!infoBubble.isOpen()) {
            infoBubble.open(map, streamPoly);
        }
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access polylines in a KmlLayer as google.maps.Polyline objects.  To open an InfoWindow (or an InfoBubble) on a KmlLayer, you need to add a listener to the KmlLayer:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(ctaLayer, 'click', function(evt) {
        if (!infoBubble.isOpen()) {
            infoBubble.setPosition(evt.latLng);
            infoBubble.open(map);
        }
    });
```

evt will be a [KmlLayerMouseEvent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlMouseEvent) which will contain information about the feature clicked

Comment: I've tried using the KmlMouseEvent properties (featureData, latLng) for event but something is still not working. It may be the tabs but not sure how to work around this. Ideally would like to get the tabbed infobubble to work!

Comment: Provide a link to your KML and I might be able to provide an example.

Comment: I've also discovered this example that combines paths with tabbed windows: http://www.grasoft.be/mtb/tracks/ShowGPX.htm?gpx=20100523.gpx It's a different approach that uses tabber. Might be worthwhile to take a look at this and see how tabber could work with a KML layer. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: 2 questions: 1. what does your code look like where you tried to use KmlMouseEvent propoerties to populate the InfoBubble tabs?  2. Where are you expecting the information to come from to populate other tabs?  The featureData goes in one, what goes in the others?